# JAVA When do comparisons evaluate to boolean values? At run-time or at compile-time?

Tags: java, boolean, comparison

In Java, When do the comparisons evaluate to boolean values? Is it at run-time or it is at compile-time? 
For instance, Imagine this:

```
int x = 6; 
if (x > 7) { doSth(); }
```

After the compilation will it be represented as "x > 7" in the bytecode or it will be represented as a boolean value "false"?

Comment: Depends on the compiler.  Some clever compilers may evaluate this at compile time.  Others will allow this to happen at runtime.

Comment: I will add to the above, that if you add a breakpoint inside the `if` block, if you debug but can't step inside then this might imply that the compiler completely optimized that `if` block away.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler.

Some compilers will try to be clever, and where possible, evaluate expressions at compile time.  Such compilers will recognise that, at the time of the `if` statement, `x` can only be `6`, and thus `x < 7` will always be false.  They may even remove the block that is guarded by this `if` statement.

However, there is no obligation for compilers to do this.  A simplistic compiler may not perform any such operations, and the entire code will make its way into the bytecode despite there being no chance of it ever being executed.